# Sql query to get sticky posts first

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am building a blog and i have a problem. There should be some sticky posts. All i want is to get first the sticky posts and then the rest.

One query that works is

```
select * from 

(
(select *,true as st from blog where "stickyUntil" > current_timestamp) 
UNION  all
(SELECT *,false as st from blog where "stickyUntil" < current_timestamp  or "stickyUntil" is null  ) 
) q 


order by st desc, "stickyUntil" DESC ,publish DESC OFFEST x LIMIT z
```

Another simpler query that workz is

```
select * from blog order by case when "stickyUntil" > current_timestamp then "stickyUntil" end desc nulls last, publish desc;
```

But this would force 200.000 rows to be sorted in memory not very fast..

Is there a way to optimize it ??

Would it be better to use two separate queries ?
Thanks

Comment: You first query looks good. Nothing wrong with a union. Is the idea that you are pulling in too many rows before you can apply the limit? Then why add a "LIMIT z" to each of the subqueries in the UNION? that will restrict the overall set returned by the subquery to a maximum of 2z records.

Comment: i though of this but it seems problem with pagination.. Then in order to determine the OFFSET at second query i would have to call a count for first query .if there are 5 stickies then an offset of 10 should be 5.. should i do this ?

Comment: @Paths Typo in the first comment, should have been "why not add a LIMIT...". Not sure I follow the question. First query has LIMIT z with no OFFSET, second query has LIMIT z with no OFFSET, and then your wrapping query remains as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) statement to avoid two passes of the table:

```
select *, 
   CASE 
   WHEN "stickyUntil" > current_timestamp THEN true
   ELSE false
   END as st
FROM blog
ORDER BY st DESC ,publish DESC OFFEST x LIMIT z
```

Postgres supports creating an [INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) on a computed field which would help here but there is a restriction:

> All functions and operators used in an index definition must be "immutable", 
>   that is, their results must depend only on their arguments and never on any 
>   outside influence (such as the contents of another table or the current time).

So you cannot index the **st** calculation. If the calculation of **st** does not need to be too accurate another option is to add the **st** field to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE blog
ADD COLUMN st boolean default true
```

[INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) **st** as a regular column:

```
CREATE INDEX sti ON blog(st)
```

And periodically run:

```
UPDATE blog
SET st = false
WHERE st = true
AND "stickyUntil" < current_timestamp
```

but having a polling process doing an update is much less attractive than a straight up query. This would only make sense if your query is really slow or there are a lot of reads of the **blog** table.

Comment: this doesnt sort the way it should.If stickyUntil datetime has passed publish should matter only... i was wondering whether there is a way to index the order...

Comment: (Whoops, just noticed my comment repeated the CASE / NULLS LAST approach you'd already tried.)

Comment: You are correct. If the order of publish takes precedence after **stickyUntil** has passed then it won't work. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: would i need a cornjob for these query ?

Comment: cronjob to perform the update? That would work yes. Or you could consider a just in time update if xxx seconds had passed since the last update.

Comment: i think that running the update query before each select should be faster(at least faster than a full table scan) as there would be 4-5 stickies so actual update should be rare. is that true? i am wondering whether an index on (stickyUntil,st) is better??

Comment: I think experiment with a few indexes/techniques and use [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) to see which has the lowest cost and which indexes are actually used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are best off running two queries, one for the sticky posts and one for the rest.

SQL does not guarantee the ordering of the results, without an explicit order by.  Although the results might seem right with the UNION ALL, you can't be guaranteed.  This becomes more apparent in a multi-threaded environment, where you do not know which thread will finish reading the data first and start returning results.

The most efficient work-around is to do it as two different queries.

Comment: i think that this is what i am going to do... although lame this might be the solution. I though of using index but seems impossible as timestamp changes..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from blog
order by 
    coalesce("stickyUntil", '1901-01-01'::date) < current_timestamp, 
    publish DESC 
OFFSET x LIMIT z
```